# How can I host Java application?

Tags: java, web-applications, hosting

I am making one application in java on my Windows 7 machine and I want to host this application to the internet.

Can I use the same machine as public server over the internet ?
What other things I need to take care for the java hosting ?

Please let me know in details because I don't know how to do hosting for java application.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use the same machine as public server over the internet ?

If you develop a server and separate client application in Java, then you can host server at your own machine and distribute clients for downloading from a website or using applets.

> What other things I need to take care for the java hosting ?

If you use your home machine you need to care to keep it always on and to have static IP-address. If your IP is not static then you should provision using no-ip.com or related service.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay this is the thing I wanted to confirm...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your Java `application` an [`applet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html).

You need to store all the files on the server and then you can put an [`<object>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT) tag on a HTML webpage, like this (supposed you transformed your application into an applet in the file `MyApplet.class`):

```
<OBJECT codetype="application/java"
        classid="java:path/to/MyApplet.class"
        width="500" height="500">
    My Applet (this text will appear if the applet cannot be loaded).
</OBJECT>
```